# What to use in the sentence: 'ability' or 'abilities'?

Tags: grammatical-number

> 1. There is no school teacher in this department who does not have his **abilities** to do classroom management.
> 2. There is no school  teacher in this department who does not have his  **ability** to  do classroom management.

Which is suitable, "ability" or "abilities"?

Comment: It depends. Please provide more context. (Here's the [edit] link for your convenience.) What aspect(s) of the teacher are you referring to when you use the words *ability* and *abilities*?

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: Regardless of whether you pluralise ***ability*** or not (syntactically and semantically they're both "valid"), your text isn't very "idiomatic" to native speakers. If you insist on using ***ability*** I'd say singular is *slightly* better, but if you switch to the more likely ***skills***, that's better in the plural. In any case, I would discard ***his***.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are grammatical. Which is better depends on what you're trying to express.

The plural form suggests a reference to particular strategies or techniques the teacher uses. For example:

> To be an effective teacher, you need (at least) three abilities:
>
> - Classroom management: the ability to manage discipline.
> - Teaching skills: the ability to impart knowledge.
> - Subject knowledge: the knowledge to impart.
>
> [- changingminds.org](http://changingminds.org/disciplines/teaching/teaching_articles/three_abilities.htm)

The singular form suggests a more innate skill:

> While some felt that they were fortunate in having "natural" teaching ability, they all emphasised the considerable amount of time they had spent in lecture and resource preparation.
>   [- Characteristics of Good Teaching, UTS](https://www.uts.edu.au/research-and-teaching/teaching-and-learning/learning-and-teaching/characteristics-good-teaching)

Comment: My +1 is primarily because I like the way you casually listed (plural) *teaching **skills*** as a (singular?) ***ability***. I'm not keen on either, but *He has teaching ability* sounds better to me than the plural version (though I'd much prefer *He has **the ability** to teach*).

Comment: Thank you @FumbleFingers, I appreciate your comment :) . I also agree that *teaching ability* is the more idiomatic of the two. The OP wants a comparison of sorts. Moving further along the lines you suggest, the OP might want to consider phrasing it as, "the other teachers are just as able to teach". Regardless of the phrasing, though, I hope they are able to settle their differences amicably.

Comment: Well, it's not obvious to me from OP's question text that the context particularly involves "comparison". Perhaps what he means to say is that every teacher has his own *particular* way of doing things (more *contrastive* than *comparative*). Or perhaps he means they're all "comparable" in that they all have (functionally equivalent) teaching skills, so none should be singled out as "less competent". A more precise context and full rephrasing of what he *wants* to convey would probably make it easier to answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The phrasing suggested a teacher who wasn't effective. If he was the standard, the other teachers were at least as good (that's what my "comparison of sorts" was referring to). Either he was trying to claim more credit than was due, or this was a prelude to an uncomfortable visit with the headmaster. Removing *his* as you suggested to the OP invalidates this interpretation. I'm holding out for yours to be what the OP intended. :)

Comment: I mean ''all teachers have their abilities''.

Comment: All I can say is that I've only just noticed OP has *already* edited the question to reflect your request for more context. But all that edit seems to have achieved is to distract us from the original point regarding singular or plural *ability* by focusing on a specific pairing with ***teaching*** where most of us probably wouldn't use *either* (because we'd use ***skills*** instead).

Comment: @learner As FumbleFingers and I see it, your question doesn't tell us enough to help you properly. Let me illustrate. Suppose I said, "I feel pain. What should I do?" Naturally, what you recommend would depend on the nature of the pain: mental vs physical, splinter-in-the-toe vs too-much-gym, etc. So you ask, "What sort of pain?", hoping to clarify. I then tell you "The type that is painful." This looks like it's giving information, but really, it communicates very little. Your comment "all teachers have their abilities" looks like that. Please add something more specific.